# Code Working in Console BUT NOT From Script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that I'm running to detect a line break in a flex-wrapped UL.

I have this javascript function at the top of my scripts.js file outside of the $(document).ready call.

```
var detectWrap = function(className) {
  var wrappedItems = [];
  var prevItem = {};
  var currItem = {};
  var items = document.getElementsByClassName(className);

  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    currItem = items[i].getBoundingClientRect();
    if (prevItem && prevItem.top < currItem.top) {
      wrappedItems.push(items[i]);
    }
    prevItem = currItem;
  };

  return wrappedItems;

}
```

Inside of a $(document).ready call, I have this:

```
$( ".menu-item-has-children" ).click(function() {
      var wrappedItems = detectWrap('menu-item-object-practice-area');
        for (var k = 0; k < wrappedItems.length; k++) {
          wrappedItems[k].className = "wrapped";
        }
    });
```

If I load the page and click the "Practice Areas", I get nothing.  If I open up the console and drop in the following it works fine:

```
var wrappedItems = detectWrap('menu-item-object-practice-area');
    for (var k = 0; k < wrappedItems.length; k++) {
    wrappedItems[k].className = "wrapped";
}
```

I'm assuming this has something to do with the timing and/or what is loaded up but I'm not adding content into the DOM...I'm just adding a class.

For reference, here is the site: https://myersbrierkelly.djykrmv8-liquidwebsites.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click the drop-down menu, two separate event handlers respond:

1. Yours, to measure for wrapped items
2. The library you're using, to toggle the display of the submenu

However, as there is nothing to manage the order of these, what ends up happening is that your wrap-detector runs *before* the submenu is shown, and if the submenu isn't shown yet then you can't measure `getBoundingClientRect()` since it doesn't exist. A simple `console.log(currItem)` would have revealed this.

If you can't guarantee the order of events (which may well be the case when using a library), then you should delay your code by a frame.

```
$(".menu-item-has-children").click(function() {
    requestAnimationFrame(function() {
        var wrappedItems...
    });
});
```